# Why did Obi-wan think the fight was over because he had the high ground?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

At the end of *Star Wars: Episode III* while Obi-wan and Anakin are fighting, Obi-wan gains the high ground and tells Anakin that the fight is over because of it.

What? The high ground has made no difference in any lightsaber fight for 3 movies. **Why would Obi-wan declare himself the victor** because of this?

---

*Note*: I'm not asking why Obi-wan won; that's already been answered in other questions. I'm asking why Obi-wan *believed he would win* for something as insignificant as having the higher ground.

Comment: Are there any canon lightsaber fights in which either combatant did in fact hold high ground?  Most of them were indoors I think ... the only comparable incident I can think of is when Qui-Gon had jumped onto the spaceship, and IIRC Darth Maul did indeed refrain from continuing the attack - not that he had much time in which to do so, but still.

Comment: It's conceivable that Obi-wan does not think the fight is over, but wants Anakin to give himself up and so will say anything to give him a reason to do that,

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Obi-Wan vs. Darth Maul.  Obi is dangling from a pipe in a bottomless pit.  Darth Maul is standing on the lip of the pit high above him.  Obi-Wan Force-jumps out of the pit and cuts Maul in two pieces.

Comment: I believe when Obi Wan said he "has the high ground" he was speaking figuratively - he simply meant "I have the advantage." In ancient warfare the high ground conveyed a decisive advantage, which is what led to this metaphorical turn of phrase. The "certain point of view" speech from the original trilogy shows that he's no stranger to speaking figuratively.

Comment: @WadCheber, good point - but perhaps we can explain that one away as Darth Maul being overconfident?  Or one could argue that a vertical jump and a jump at an angle are completely different from a tactical standpoint, and probably any experienced lightsaber fighter could explain why. :-)  (But I'd have to watch both scenes again to decide which explanation, if either, actually makes sense.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - The best explanation is "Darth Maul is a moron".  He stands at the top of the pit, scraping his lightsaber on the ground to make pretty sparks, when he should have been...  you know...  hacking off Obi-Wan's hands so he fell to his death.

Comment: @WadCheber No, the best explanation is "plot" and Lucas' inability to avoid such blatant contradictions.

Comment: I think this is a great question if only for the fact that Obi-Wan himself witnessed a case where the high ground meant nothing (when Darth Maul had the high ground against him). If the high ground didn't grant Maul the victory why would Obi-Wan think he'd won?

Comment: @Richard because it's about what Obi-wan thought,  not the actual battle.

Comment: @Richard Exactly. Subtle yet important difference.

Comment: High ground in this case can be likened to the adrenaline rush nicknamed *runner's high*. Obi just had that "I'mma going to kick your butt" frame of mind.

Comment: @WadCheber: Darth absolutely disrespected ObiWan as an opponent, to such an extent that he was toying with ObiWan. If Darth had said, "Go ahead, try to jump out of there and take me", and had then prepared himself for the move, I believe it would have ended differently. Remember, ObiWan has the high ground here AND is prepared for an attempt to overcome that advantage.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7FMh3YtK_w) should explain everything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is explained in the [Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)). In short, Obi-Wan is so utterly familiar with Anakin's fighting style and capabilities that he knows that having the high ground will give him a slight advantage, forcing Anakin to jump into an attack and that that tiny benefit will be sufficient for Obi-Wan to win.

> ***Blade-to-blade, they were identical.*** After thousands of hours in
>   lightsaber sparring, **they knew each other better than brothers**, more
>   intimately than lovers; they were complementary halves of a single
>   warrior.

Comment: "more intimately than lovers" *raises eyebrows*

Comment: @RogueJedi - *More* intimately. e.g. There was no hanky-panky.

Comment: @Valorum Dude, you're killing perfectly good fandom ships here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I've been trying to spread the rumour that Rey's parents are Jar Jar and Mon Mothma but no-one seems to be biting.

Comment: @Valorum No, that's not true... that's impossible!

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - I think you mean "[Noooooooo!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWaLxFIVX1s)"